# Grub recover - install Ubuntu, keep Win7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, dual-boot, grub

I messed up the grub loader by accident and all tutorials to install it again failed. Now I can't boot anything so I created an Ubuntu Boot Stick to access all my data. When I tried to reinstall the grub loader I have had several different errors like

- error no such device
- failed to get cannonical path of /cow
- file /grub/i386-pc/normal.mod can not be found
- the command normal and insmod normal cannot be found

and even more. So I give up and I would like to ask if it is safe to reinstall Ubuntu and keep Win7. Ubuntu offers an option via the boot stick I created to do so, but in the last step there is a warning that the boot sector of one partition will be changed and one partition will be overwritten. I do not care about the installed Ubuntu partition, this one can be overwritten. But the Win7 partition should stay untouched. Is there a way to find out and to be sure nothing of Win7 will be deleted or will the setup be so intelligent on its own?

Edit: As far as I know I put Grub in sda2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I have, this leads to grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
That is why I kind of gave up since there are no important data on the Ubuntu installation anyway. I simply would like to keep the Win7 installation safe without any loss.

Comment: Just did it. Unfortunately I do not know a lot about this system as it was only my backup system and I usually do not work a lot with linux. I will try to burn the boot repair on a stick and try to repair the grub loader once again. But so far every attempt failed.

Comment: Please click [edit] and, using a LiveUSB flashdrive, find the assignments of sda1, sda2, sda3, et cetera, then tell us what you find. Windows 7 _could_ use EFI (which would be the first partition) but most Windows 7 installs are legacy instead (so we have to check).

Comment: have you tried boot recover disk and easy BCD?

Comment: Someone is digging up graves here, eh? Anyway, thanks for your help. The solution back then was the LiveUSB flashdrive :)